# How to open a pptx file in powerpoint using python?

Tags: python, python-pptx, python-os

I am developing a desktop application that helps users create Powerpoint Presentations. After finishing and saving the .pptx file,  is there a way to get it to open in powerpoint so that the user can see the resulting presentation without having to open the file on their own ? (I am using windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) function, which will start a file with its associated application. This will behave like double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer

```
>>> import os
>>> os.startfile("path_of_your_ppt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
os.system('your pptx filename with .pptx extension')
```

If your windows will know which default app to use for opening PowerPoint files, this will surely work.